# Word for having a business buy an item from its own stock to use in the course of its own operations?

Tags: single-word-requests

I once worked at a grocery store, and occasionally we would need a product in the course of business that we sold.  In that case, we would sometimes take the item off the shelf, and ring it up a special way to "sell" it to the store.  Basically, a way of marking it out of inventory and noting that it was for operational use.

For instance, if during the course of business we needed dish soap to wash some dishes by hand, we would grab a container of dish soap off the shelves and put it through this process so that we could use it.

I think it was a short simple word, maybe four letters long.  Something like "Please grab some dish soap from the shelves and ____ it," or maybe "Please grab some dish soap from the shelves and ____ it out."

I'm having trouble finding this answer in a web search or a search on this site.

Answer (score 4):

From a desperately difficult time I spent in my younger years managing a Walgreens, I can say that we used the word "expense".

> Please grab some dish soap from the shelves and expense it.

Endless respect to all retail and service workers.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expense) has *expense* as a verb with the meaning "to write off as an expense". That seems to match this usage, although it's not clear from the dictionary exactly what context it is used in.

Comment: Can one ever really understand why corporations adapt the meaning of a word to their own purposes?

Comment: To "expense" something means to charge its cost to the overheads (running costs) of the business.  Nothing odd about it.

Comment: It is a good word +1 ; We used it in my previous company too , in a slightly mismatching way : When we buy 5 items from "outside the company" & use 3 items for "company purpose" (2 items for personal use) then we upload the receipt & "expense" the 3 items only , @BillJ , We did not use it for "internal purchase" like OP wants. Eg : take client for lunch & include wine , then upload the receipt & "expense" the lunch , without the wine. Depending on the item , when ordering internally , we used the words "requisition" (hardware with approval) or "indent" (stationary without approval) or similar.

Comment: @Prem In a situation like the one in the OP's example, we would typically obtain the value from the latest stock list and use that value with its corresponding stock ref/nominal code to journal the cost from the balance sheet stock to P&L overheads. I'm assuming, of course, that the dish soap or whatever is of sufficient value to have been booked as a stock item in the first place. Items of insignificant cost would not be booked at all.

Comment: I am not speaking for the OP , I am speaking only what I know about , @BillJ , hence if OP wants that word , I am fine with it. I am sure OP will not want the words listed in my answer. We will not know the "Exact Word" which OP used , unless OP confirms it one way or the other.

Comment: "Expense" doesn't quite ring true with my memory, but the feel of it and its usage in the sentence is definitely the same.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stopped in a different branch of the same grocery store chain, and asked the worker there.  The two terms she gave me were:

- store use
- house charge

Neither of these match my memory of the word or how it was used in a sentence.  But I figure there's value in sharing which words are currently (years later) in use for the concept within the chain.

Comment: Nice to know that. It matches my earlier comment [ More-over , it could well turn out to be some internal jargon which only that store used (( Eg "I will XXXX it [out]" where XXXX = mark,chip,haze,axin )) which we outsiders will never know ! ]

Answer (score 0):

Some Choices & thoughts :

We can try to use these :

> (1) self-invoice
> (2) self-indent
> (3) self-PO
> (4) internal-requisition

Here , "self" refers to company , while "internal" refers to the intended usage.

The Basis for the Suggestions are the meanings of the individual words . . .

> [indent](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=indent)
>
> > [Brit] An order for goods to be exported or imported

> [invoice](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=invoice)
>
> > An itemized statement of money owed for goods shipped or services rendered

> [purchase order](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=purchase%20order)
>
> > A commercial document used to request someone to supply something in return for payment and providing specifications and quantities

> [requisition](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=requisition)
>
> > Make a formal request for official services
> > Demand and take for use or service, especially by military or public authority for public service

In general , there will some "corporate" account which will "pay" for the items & will permit some level of auditing & tracking.

Some real-life usages & references :
https://oboloo.com/glossary/internal-purchase-order-process/
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/po/ireqov.htm
https://tipalti.com/purchase-requisitions-vs-purchase-orders/
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/internal-purchase-orders-within-same-site-and-organization

Comment: Question is currently locked & I can not comment there. It seems that OP is not looking to get some choices to use. OP is trying to remember a specific word used at a specific grocery store a long time ago. I think all choices are bound to be hit-&-miss guess-work & unlikely to match ! More-over , it could well turn out to be some internal jargon which only that store used (( Eg "I will XXXX it [out]" where XXXX = mark,chip,haze,axin )) which we outsiders will never know !

Comment: You've obviously never worked in company finance! See Melisa's answer and my comment thereto.

Comment: Even if we don't hit on a word that matches my memory from way back, I think this has been an interesting linguistic question.